# jwplayer onTime() calling setInterval() several times per second

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

My main goal is at 7:45 in the video to display a countdown timer from 20:00.

Here is my event called by the jwplayer I'm using:

```
onTime: function(event){showTimer(event.position);}
```

Here is my funciton showTimer:

```
   function showTimer(video_position){
       // Schedule the update to happen once every second
       if(Math.round(video_position) == 465){
           setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
       }
   };
```

The Problem:
Because it onTime() isn't guaranteed to hit right at 465.0 I have to d a Math.round on the video position. If I do this, 4-10 onTime event handlers knock off within 465.0 - 466.0 so my setInterval() gets called several times and the timer counts down insanely fast.

Is there a way to make it hit the setInterval() once or maybe a global variable I can set the first time to let setInterval() know its already been knocked off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just use a boolean flag to check whether the event has fired yet.

```
var fired = false;
if(Math.round(video_position) == 465 && !fired){
   fired = true;
   setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
}
```

That way it can only fire the event once.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be set to false again once the function showTimer gets hit again?

Comment: You'd have to stick the fired variable outside of the showTimer function for this to work.

Comment: So simple. Sometimes I just want to konk myself on the head.